# sharepoint button Name

Tags: sharepoint-2007

In SP Designer, How do I change the default text in the button. Like OK--Submit and Cancel--Go Back.

Can I change it, If yes what where does the mapping goes ..

Thank you..

Comment: it really depends where you are. Are you talking about InfoPath Forms? Use InfoPath. Are you talking of aspx pages? You can change the buttons there. There is no general resource file you could change to have all "OK" buttons spell "Alright".

Comment: I have to change it in ASPx page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the text of Buttons in case of custom List Form

Right Click on OK Button select proporties

1. Select Indesgin as True
2. Change the Text to Submit

Repeat above steps for Cancel button as well

Comment: thank You. That worked. One more thing Can I put a aspx button to signout from the site. I am talking in SP Designer. this is basically to logout by just clicking the button.

Comment: Are you using Farm Based authentication or Windows based authentication

Comment: We are using form based authentication from AD

Comment: in case if you are using windows based authentication solution is simple create a html button and use it to redirect to "http://<siteurl>/_layouts/SignOut.aspx" i'm not sure if this will work with FBA but you try this thier as well else you would have to use javascripts to remove authentication cookies from your browser